# mathds font not working:(

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I am using TeX Live (Win 7). My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,amsfonts,dsfont} 

\begin{document}
$\mathds{N}$
\end{document}
```

But it doesn't produce the desired mathds font. This problem has been bothering me for a long time. Anyone can help me out? Thank you!

After I added `\listfiles` in the preamble as asked by @Harish Kumar, below is what I got:

```
*File List*

 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class

  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)

 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features

 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01

  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0

  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d

  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names

 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support

  amsthm.sty    2004/08/06 v2.20

mathrsfs.sty    1996/01/01 Math RSFS package v1.0 (jk)

  dsfont.sty    1995/08/01 v0.1 Double stroke roman fonts

    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A

    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B

   ursfs.fd    1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)

 ***********
```

The log file can be found here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29066158/font.log

[image]

Comment: It does in Miktex for me. Can you please add `\listfiles` in your preamble and post the `*File list` in your question? May be you are using old distribution!

Comment: Hey Kumar, thank you for your reply. I added the file list in my question now.

Comment: It works in texlive, does your log file list font substitution warnings

Comment: Strange. I too have `dsfont.sty    1995/08/01 v0.1 Double stroke roman fonts`. I am cluless!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did get some warnings: LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted. But still no idea how to fix this...

Comment: Your distribution is missing the file `udsrom.fd`. I have it in the directory `c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/doublestroke/` where `dsfont.sty` is. But you have the latter in the directory `c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/dsfont/`. Try reinstalling the `doublestroke` package in TeX Live

Comment: @karlkoeller This seems to be on the right track. I reinstalled doublestroke package. However, I still got some error message: "The command name is C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find dsrom10.mf. ! Font U/dsrom/m/n/10.95=dsrom10 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
 found." Could you figure out the problem here? Thank you so much!